# Get total count for the multiple select queries and return as single table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get total of all the below four counts of the separate `SQL` queries and return as single table as below:

[image]

```
select count(*) OpenTaskCount from [COM].[USER_GENERATED_TASK_LIST] where TASK_STATUS = 'Active' and ACTIVE_FLAG = 1     
select count(*) AnsweredTaskCount from [COM].[USER_GENERATED_TASK_LIST] where TASK_STATUS = 'Active' and ACTIVE_FLAG = 0     
select count(*) CandidateTaskCount from [COM].[USER_GENERATED_TASK_LIST] where TASK_STATUS = 'Active' and ACTIVE_FLAG = 1 and TASK_ASSIGNED_DTM >= DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE())    
select count(*) AlertTaskCount from [COM].[USER_GENERATED_TASK_LIST] where TASK_STATUS = 'Active' and ACTIVE_FLAG = 1 and TASK_ASSIGNED_DTM <= DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE())
```

Is there any easy method to get the total task from the above select queries and then return as single row.

Comment: in Mariadb each of those SELECT statements could be a field in a wrapper select: e,g, SELECT (select count(*) OpenTaskCount from ...),(select count(*) AnsweredTaskCount  from ...),(select count(*) CandidateTaskCount  from ...),(select count(*) AlertTaskCount from ...);   Maybe try that?

Comment: You're counting double, both CandidateTaskCount and AlertTaskCount are already part of OpenTaskCount so your TotalTask should be 81+17 = 98

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation, such as:

```
select
    Sum(case when ACTIVE_FLAG = 1 then 1 else 0 end) OpenTaskCount,
    Sum(case when ACTIVE_FLAG = 0 then 1 else 0 end) AnsweredTaskCount,
    Sum(case when ACTIVE_FLAG = 1 and TASK_ASSIGNED_DTM >= DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE()) then 1 else 0 end) CandidateTaskCount,
    Sum(case when ACTIVE_FLAG = 1 and TASK_ASSIGNED_DTM <= DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE()) then 1 else 0 end) AlertTaskCount
from COM.USER_GENERATED_TASK_LIST
where TASK_STATUS = 'Active';
```

Edit - to add a total column I'd probably just use a derived table, like:

```
select OpenTaskCount, AnsweredTaskCount, CandidateTaskCount, AlertTaskCount,
  OpenTaskCount + AnsweredTaskCount + CandidateTaskCount + AlertTaskCount as TotalTask
from (
  select 
    Sum(case when ACTIVE_FLAG = 1 then 1 else 0 end) OpenTaskCount,
    Sum(case when ACTIVE_FLAG = 0 then 1 else 0 end) AnsweredTaskCount,
    Sum(case when ACTIVE_FLAG = 1 and TASK_ASSIGNED_DTM >= DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE()) then 1 else 0 end) CandidateTaskCount,
    Sum(case when ACTIVE_FLAG = 1 and TASK_ASSIGNED_DTM <= DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE()) then 1 else 0 end) AlertTaskCount
  from COM.USER_GENERATED_TASK_LIST
  where TASK_STATUS = 'Active'
)t;
```

Comment: Can you help me to return total of all 4 as its 5th column.

Comment: Is that really a "total" as you're counting rows more than once?

Comment: @Lim see additional edit above.

Comment: there would always be a single row with this logic. But at last column i need to get the total all the others counts

Answer (score 1):

You may try with conditional aggregation and the appropriate `CASE` expressions (the `NULL` values are eliminated by an aggregate):

```
SELECT 
   OpenTaskCount = COUNT(CASE WHEN TASK_STATUS = 'Active' AND ACTIVE_FLAG = 1 THEN 1 END),
   AnsweredTaskCount = COUNT(CASE WHEN TASK_STATUS = 'Active' and ACTIVE_FLAG = 0 THEN 1 END),
   CandidateTaskCount = COUNT(CASE WHEN TASK_STATUS = 'Active' and ACTIVE_FLAG = 1 and TASK_ASSIGNED_DTM >= DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE()) THEN 1 END),
   AlertTaskCount = COUNT(CASE WHEN TASK_STATUS = 'Active' and ACTIVE_FLAG = 1 and TASK_ASSIGNED_DTM <= DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE()) THEN 1 END)
   TotalTask = COUNT(CASE WHEN
     (TASK_STATUS = 'Active' AND ACTIVE_FLAG = 1) OR        
     (TASK_STATUS = 'Active' and ACTIVE_FLAG = 0) OR
     (TASK_STATUS = 'Active' and ACTIVE_FLAG = 1 and TASK_ASSIGNED_DTM >= DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE())) OR
     (TASK_STATUS = 'Active' and ACTIVE_FLAG = 1 and TASK_ASSIGNED_DTM <= DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE()))
                     THEN 1 END)
FROM [COM].[USER_GENERATED_TASK_LIST]
```

Comment: I also need to return total count as 5th column. Can you help me to achieve that also.

Comment: @Lim, simply add all conditions, combined with `OR`, in a different `CASE` expression.

Comment: I checked above query. All other fields are fine but it's giving wrong total count

Comment: @Lim, you need to combine all four `WHERE` caluses in the 5th `CASE` expression, nothing more. Probably some test data will help here. Based on the sample data, the `TotalCount` sums all four conditional counts.